Haskell pattern matching on a list of lists - why doesn't this work?
I have the following definitions in my Haskell code:
-- A region has a list of squares, and a list of possible combinations of values,
-- all of which add up to the same total.
data Region = Region [Square] [[Int]] deriving (Show, Eq)

-- The total which each combination adds up to: if the list of combinations is
-- empty it is 0, otherwise it is the sum of the first combination.
total :: Region -> Int
total (Region _ []) = 0
total (Region _ [c:_]) = sum c

This code fails to compile with the following error:
* Couldn't match expected type `t0 Int' with actual type `Int'
    * In the first argument of `sum', namely `c'
      In the expression: sum c
      In an equation for `total': total (Region _ [c : _]) = sum c

I'm probably missing something very obvious here, but I don't understand why the compiler thinks the type of c is Int, when the pattern match tells it to bind c to the first element of a list of [Int]. What is going on?

The pattern [c:_], is short for [(c:_)], so c is the first item in the first (and only) sublist, not the first sublist. So c here is an Int, not an [Int], you should use:
total :: Region -> Int
total (Region _ []) = 0
total (Region _ (c:_)) = sum c

Wow. That's not very intuitive. But thank you, that has indeed solved my problem.

@JeremyHicks: No, I like the Prolog syntax for lists more, although I think it can not be done easily in Haskell, because (:) is to some extent, just an operator.

@JeremyHicks: [term] as an expression is a list of one item, so it is as a pattern, too, no matter what term is.

@JonPurdy: Yes, but where I studied, we saw Haskell immediately after Prolog, and Prolog uses [] and [H|T] for empty list and "cons", so that resulted in some people having to debug a lot :).
